# Inequality among trigonometric sums of normal random variables

Tags: analysis, inequality, self-learning

This is an inequality used in a proof which I do not know how to prove.

$$\left(\sum_{k = 2^j +1}^{2^{j+1}} \frac{\sin(k\pi t)}{k}G_k\right)^2 \leq \left|\sum_{k = 2^j +1}^{2^{j+1}} \frac{e^{ik\pi t}}{k}G_k\right|^2 =\sum_{k = 2^j +1}^{2^{j+1}} \sum_{l = 2^j +1}^{2^{j+1}} \frac{e^{ik\pi t} e^{-il\pi t}}{kl} G_k G_l,$$ where $G_k \sim N(0,1).$

**Update**: There is a further inequality following from the previous one. It seems that here we use the fact that $e^{im\pi t}$ is a unit complex number. Once again, however, I cannot see why we can compare a complex number with a real number.

$$\sum_{l = 2^j+1}^{2^{j+1}-m} \frac{e^{im\pi t}}{l(l+m)} G_lG_{l+m} \leq \left|\sum_{l = 2^j+1}^{2^{j+1}-m} \frac{G_lG_{l+m}}{l(l+m)} \right|.$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since $G_k$ are real,
$$\sum_{k = 2^j +1}^{2^{j+1}} \frac{\sin(k\pi t)}{k}G_k = \Im \left( \sum_{k = 2^j +1}^{2^{j+1}} \frac{e^{ik\pi t}}{k}G_k\right)$$

Comment: @achillehui Thanks. What about the second part? How to get rid of the absolute sign? To be more specific, how can we compare real and complex number since complex numbers cannot be ordered.

Comment: @20824 The second one comes from $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$ as you pointed out. In this case, $z$ is a sum, so it's the product of two sums, and then distributed.

Comment: The second part simply expands the whole thing out. For example, consider the case your sum contains only two terms, you have $$|a + b|^2 = (a+b)(\bar{a}+\bar{b}) = a\bar{a} + a\bar{b} + b\bar{a} + b\bar{b}$$ Even individual terms in the sum contains complex numbers, the imaginary part in the final sum cancels out.